# Node JS ,Trying to installed forked github repo but failing , what is missing?

Tags: node.js, git, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have forked [this repo](https://github.com/ninjavungve/forward-deeplink)  into my own which is [this one](https://github.com/32xnabin/forward-deeplink.git) now to install this forked repo I have tried everything like npm install git+{giturl}   npm install {user}/{repo} but I end up getting the following error:
Note: I am trying to install inside docker environment

```
docker-compose exec app npm install git+https://github.com/32xnabin/forward-deeplink.git

npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/32xnabin/forward-deeplink.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Note: I needed git installed docker image .. that solved the issue.

Comment: is this on windows?  You might need to install git

Comment: @Joe ubuntu 20.04 and I do have git

Comment: `enoent undefined ls-remote` implies that NPM can't find git.  is it in your path?  It should be `git ls-remote`

Comment: its inside of docker the actual command is "docker-compose exec app npm install git+https://github.com/32xnabin/forward-deeplink.git" I will update that in the question as well.

Comment: Does your docker image have git installed?

Comment: I am not authorized to add packages on git, but I can see its not

Comment: _"I am not authorized to add packages on git"_... I have no idea what this means but what image are you attempting to use? You can always use your own docker `context` in compose and provide your own `Dockerfile` with whatever tools you want installed

Comment: yes but when I push my codes wheoever wants to test might need to do the same in docker right? but thanks, the issue is pin pointed now

Comment: You have a docker container called `app`, but that tells us *nothing* about what image it might be running or what might be going on in that container.  If it's your own Dockerfile, you haven't even disclosed what its base image is.  You'll need to use a base image that has git, or you'll need to add RUN commands to your Dockerfile to get git installed in your image.

Comment: understood guys thanks

Comment: FROM node:12.8.0-alpine

Comment: few services and conatiners

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+alpine+npm+ERR%21+enoent+undefined+ls-remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node Alpine images [do not come with `git` installed](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/pull/367). What you can do is install it yourself into your `Dockerfile`

```sh
FROM node:12.8.0-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add git

# and so on
```

Other options are to use one of the Debian based images like `node:12.8.0-buster` which comes with `git` pre-installed.

---

FYI Node v12 will be out of maintenance soon. The current LTS release is v14. See https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/